# Table Rate Shipping Extension

Tags: extensions, shipping, shipping-methods, table-rates, multiple

Does  anyone know of a multiple table rate extension for Magento 2.0? Have used Webshopapps Premium Matrix Rates with Magento 1.9 and it was great but they are not making it available for 2.0.

I want to have 2 or 3 shipping choices and be able to specify an extra rate per unit of weight e.g. base price $2 plus $1 per extra 200g.

Comment: The only extension available is https://magecomp.com/magento-2-matrix-rates.html

Answer (score 2):

I saw these guys [Cedcommerce](http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions#/page/5) have done many extensions on Magento2, but they on the development mode I asked them about the table rate extension in the live chat once, and they answer they need a couple of weeks to release it, here is the extension [PREMIUM MATRIX RATE](http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/premium-matrix-rate).
So I guess we need to wait and see, cause in my company, we didn't find anyone did it, else webshopapps of course.